# How to sort array based on naming structure

Tags: powershell

I've built a small report which essentially just does a row counts for Excel files within a share. However, there is now a requirement for the report to display the directory count in a specific order.

I cannot fathom how I'd go about that.

```
#Searching location
$searchinfolder = '\\Report\testing\'
#Creation of Array. 
$data = @()
#Get Child items where not folder object and directory not "Postions" 
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path  $searchinfolder -Recurse | Where { ! $_.Directory.Name -ne "Positions" }  
Foreach ($File in $Files) { 
    #Main section. Get csv files, does a row count after removing top 2 and last 3 lines. 
        $fileStats = Get-Content $File.FullName | Select-Object -Skip 2 | Select-Object -SkipLast 3  | Measure-Object -line
        $linesInFile = $fileStats.Lines - 1
       #Added a counter because arrays start at 0.. need to start at 1. 
        $linesInFile++
        #Only gets files with data in them. 
        if ($linesInFile -gt 0) {  
            $data += @(
                [pscustomobject]@{
                Filename = $File.fullname; 
                Rowcount = $linesInFile; 
                Directory = $File.Directory.Name 
                })
    } 
}

#Group by directory and get total sum of each file. 
$data = $data | Group-Object Directory | ForEach-Object { 
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Directory = $_.Group.Directory | Get-Unique
        Rowcount  = ($_.Group.Rowcount | Measure-Object -sum).Sum
    }
}
```

So for example, let's say the folder structure we're scraping is Cat, Dog, Goat, Programmer, Lama, Mouse.

Let's say all the folders but 1 contain files. How would I go about having the $data array arranged in a specific order of choosing? Furthermore, how would you go about setting the order and just skipping to the next assigned directory if the current directory is empty?

See below my attempt at pseudo-code trying to explain this.

```
Foreach ($item in $data){ 
if ($item.directory -eq "cat") { $item = $array[0] } 
if ($item.directory -eq "dog") { $item = $array[1] } 
if ($item.directory -eq "goat") { $item = $array[2] } 
if ($item.directory -eq "Programmer") { $item = $array[3] } 
if ($item.directory -eq "Lama") { $item = $array[4] } 
if ($item.directory -eq "Mouse") { $item = $array[5] } 
}
```

Comment: _"How would I go about having the $data array arranged in a specific order of choosing?"_ which order? Your code is very confusing and your question is very hard to understand

Comment: My Array contains the folders from the get-child-Item. 

How would you go about arranging the order of the folders in an order of your choosing? I want to pick the order of the array.

Comment: Create an outer loop to loop through the items/subfolders (rather than the whole root search folder): `"cat", "dog", "goat", "Programmer", "Lama", "Mouse" |ForEach-Object {$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path  $searchinfolder$_ -Recurse ...`